# ThinkPad x230 Windows Hello

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, fingerprint, windows-hello

I have a ThinkPad x230i (2324-HF4) with a fingerprint reader on it.

I've upgraded up to Windows 10 and I can't enable fingerprint login.

In BIOS settings fingerprint reader is visible (I can erase all data on it).

In Windows device manager it is also visible.

How can I fix thix error?

Fingerprint ID is: USB\VID_147E&PID_2020

Comment: Have you updated the Lenovo drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my trouble by installing other windows iso.

As I can undestand, my old  image wasn't contain hello feature